# Is using NuGet .NET packages from PowerShell really this cumbersome?

Tags: .net, powershell, google-api, nuget-package, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been exploring how to use use google APIs from PowerShell.

1. Ensure nuget.org is a trusted package source

   ```
   Register-PackageSource -name nuget.org -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 -Provider NuGet -Trusted
   ```
2. Install .NET api packages:

   ```
   $googlePackages= @(
       'Google.Apis'
       'Google.Apis.Core'
       'Google.Apis.Discovery.v1'
   )
   Install-Package -Name $googlePackages
   ```
3. In your actual script, `Add-Type` each assembly for each package you need to use. This is the really annoying part.

   The packages contains assemblies for different platforms. `Add-Type` needs to be passed the right versions of the assemblies. The function `Add-PackageAssemblies` below tries to encapsulate this.

   `Add-Type` will fail because of missing types. Through trial and error, other packages whose assemblies needed to be `Add-Type`d can be found.

   ```
   function Add-PackageTypes {
       Param (
           [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
           [Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity] 
           $package
           ,
           $assemblyFilter = "*netstandard2.0*.dll"
       )
       Process {
           $assemblies = get-childitem -path ($package.Source | Split-Path -Parent) -Recurse |
               Where-Object {$_.FullName -like $assemblyFilter } |
               Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
           try {
               $newTypes = Add-Type -AssemblyName $assemblies -passthru
           } catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException] {
               Write-Error "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
               Write-Error "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"
           }
           Write-Output $newTypes
       }
   }

   $types = Get-Package $googlePackages | Add-PackageTypes
   ```

   It would be nice to avoid the trial and error and use package properties to find and load other required types.
4. Finally, actually use the APIs:

   ```
   $serviceInitializer = New-Object Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService+Initializer
   $serviceInitializer.ApiKey = Get-MySecretGoogleAPIKey
   $serviceInitializer.ApplicationName = "DiscoverySamplePowershellApplication"
   $discoveryService = New-Object Google.Apis.Discovery.v1.DiscoveryService -ArgumentList $serviceInitializer
   $results = $discoveryService.apis.List().Execute()

   Write-Output $results.items
   ```

Is there an easier way? Is there already a well-known module that resolves these issues?

Comment: It really is complicated at the moment - [here's a proposal to change that](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6724).

Comment: It's cumbersome enough that when I have to use a package, I usually go to nuget.org, download the .nupkg file manually, extract it with 7-zip (it's just a zip file) and then `Add-Type -Path` to what I'm actually going to use.  However, I'm usually working with essentially standalone libraries like Json.NET or iTextSharp or CSVReader.

Comment: @BaconBits : Yes, but the literal paths feel pretty bad; impacts portability.

Comment: @mkelement0 : Reading through your outline of loading types on Mac proves I've only barely scratched the surface.

Comment: @BaconBits: How do you load the dependencies? I'm completely baffled by the fact, that all my attempts to use `Add-Type` fail because NuGet doesn't place .dlls into a single directory.

Comment: @JariTurkia I go to, for example, [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and download the package using the link on the right. Then I open the .nupkg file with 7-Zip (or rename it to a .zip file). Then I go into the lib folder. Then I pick the version of the library that matches PowerShell's CLR version from `$PSVersionTable` or .Net Standard. I extract all those files to a single directory, usually where my project script will be. Then I `Add-Type -Path $PathToDll`. If you need multiple DLLs, read the package doc or run `Add-Type` for each.

Comment: Thanks for the info @BaconBits. I'm looking for a generic solution to download and load any NuGet-library to Powershell. What you're describing will work for some libraries, but there are others which require a specific .Net dependency-library. `Install-Package` will work and download all dependencies to bunch of directories. `Add-Type` won't find all those .dlls and will eventually fail.